# Why is gdisk's default starting sector different than the first available?

Tags: linux

When creating a new partition on an empty drive with gdisk, it tells me the default first sector is 2048.  Why not 34?
`First sector (34-1953458142, default = 2048) or {+-}size{KMGTP}:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from `man gdisk`:

```
   l      Change the sector alignment value. Disks with more logical sectors per physical  sec-
          tors  (such as modern Advanced Format drives), some RAID configurations, and many SSD
          devices, can suffer performance problems if partitions are not aligned  properly  for
          their  internal data structures. On new disks, GPT fdisk attempts to align partitions
          on 2048-sector (1MiB) boundaries by default, which optimizes performance for  all  of
          these disk types. On pre-partitioned disks, GPT fdisk attempts to identify the align-
          ment value used on that disk, but will set 8-sector alignment on  disks  larger  than
          300  GB  even  if  lesser  alignment  values  are detected. In either case, it can be
          changed by using this option.
```

To change this value, you can do this on the `gdisk` command line:

```
x
l
1
m
```

(`x` to enter expert mode.  `l` to change alignment. `1` to set it to 1 sector. `m` to return to the main menu.)

Now you can create a new partition (command `n`).  Now it can start at sector 34.  But better abstain from this if you have a modern drive like `SSD`.  Most modern drives have 4K blocks, this is at least an alignment of 8.  This allows a start of sector 40.

If you are puzzled why you cannot start at sector 8 in that case:

The GPT reserves a lot more space for the partitioning data than the "old traditional partitioning".  And there still is the MBR which keeps some compatiblity to the old partitioning.  Hence the first 34 sectors and the last 33 sectors of each drive are used up for GPT, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table).